# How to create components with children that are components?

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm trying to implement something in React in a really neat manner and I need to be able to create components that I can use like so:

```js
<>
    <MyComponent>
        <MyComponent.Title>
            Some Random String passed in
        </MyComponent.Title>
        <MyComponent.Body>
            Some JSX tags passed in... something with classnames and maybe even listeners
        </MyComponent.Body>
    </MyComponent>
</>
```

However, I do not know where to start or what to look into. A little guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding what you need, basically you have to pass props first into the MyComponent from the function:

```
function MyComponent({title, image, bodytext}) {
  <TitleComponent title={title}/>
  <BodyComponent bodytext={bodytext}
}
```

Then from the other components you will receive the props and render out in JSX:

```
function TitleComponent({title}) {
return ( <h1>{title}</h1> )
}
```

Do the same for the body text.

Comment: The thing is that I want to be able to pass the HTML tags and other things into the component as children. In the manner I described in my question.

Comment: Can you please explain me exactly what you need to do?

Comment: I want to make a js file that exports multiple components that can be called as a single instance.